Payment Method Issue in Stripe Subscription from Flutter App
I am trying to add a stripe subscription to a Mobile App that is developed on Flutter Framework and this Mobile App does not have a backend. I am kind of confused as I have added all the APIs from Stripe like creating a Customer, creating a price, creating a payment method and then creating the subscription.
Now comes the confusion part while creating the payment method from the API it gives me the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. To continue processing use Stripe.js, the Stripe mobile bindings, or Stripe Elements. For more information, see https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/integration/settings. If you are qualified to handle card data directly, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis.",
        "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_775vPrs4OZmBKF?t=1713787864",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}

I know that what the error says is that I cannot send the card numbers directly it is unsafe. So I have read many tutorials that say to create card tokens first then and I have created tokens as well from the APIs but still it gives me the same error and I tried to create the payment method from the code but there is no way that I can pass the card numbers and other stuff through the Flutter and what it says is that only enter the billing details, shipping details and mandate details.
So, I am using flutter_stripe plugin.
So please help me, how can I send the card numbers into the Payment Method to create it and then add PaymentMethodID into the Subscription.
Thanks

You must have a back end server process to communicate with Stripe. There are secrets involved that cannot be held securely in the mobile app. Note that if your subscription is for delivery of content or services in the app then you must use in app  Apple/Google. You can only use Stripe if the subscription is for real-world services like a gym membership.

My subscription is for medical services and Google Pay does not approve for medical services that is why I chose Stripe and now this is the problem I am getting.

Ok. You need a server to process the payments.

you need to use flutter_stripe package and use this code to take a payment method Id, then attach created payment method to your customer id after that create a subscription with given id and handle subscription status if done or incomplete


final paymentMethod = await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
        params: PaymentMethodParams.card(
            paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(
                billingDetails: BillingDetails(email: donation.email))));



